# Error while converting PDF to image using PDFBox on Java 32 bit

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox library for converting PDF document to image. For 32 bit java I am getting error saying 'java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.' Stacktrace given below.
I am using Apache Tomcat 8 on linux server. PDFBox version used is 1.8.11.
Java version 8 is used.
But running the same code using 64 bit java, PDF document is getting converted to image without any issues. Would appreciate any help on this.

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2Font.getawtFont(PDCIDFontType2Font.java:82)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.getawtFont(PDType0Font.java:92)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont.drawString(PDSimpleFont.java:110)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.processTextPosition(PageDrawer.java:260)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processEncodedText(PDFStreamEngine.java:504)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.ShowText.process(ShowText.java:56)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:562)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:269)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:236)
at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:216)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:801)
```

Comment: We might be able to help you if you shared the PDF in question. Furthermore, the exact Java details (JRE? JDK? Complete version number?) might be of interest.

Comment: I'd recommend to update to PDFBox 2.0.*. The result of the investigation will likely be that the font is broken. PDFBox 2.0 has better rendering and is more lenient.